# How nextClearBit() of BitSet in java actually works?

Tags: java, bitset

This method in BitSet class is used to return the index of the first bit that is set to false

```
import java.util.BitSet;
public class BitSetDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      BitSet b = new BitSet();
      b.set(5);
      b.set(9);
      b.set(6);
      System.out.println(""+b);
      System.out.println(b.nextClearBit(5));
      System.out.println(b.nextClearBit(9)); 
     }
   }
 Output :
 {5, 6, 9}
 7
 10
```

In this code, 6 is set after 9 but it shows that the values are stored consecutively ((b.nextClearBit(5) returns next value which is 7). So, how BitSet store these values ?

Comment: Have you looked at the source? What was unclear about it? Also, according to your output, the output of `nextClearBit(5)` is 7, as expected (and not 6 as you say).

Comment: Oops sorry it is 7. Will it store the values consecutively?

Comment: The javadoc documents its behaviour, look at the source if you want to know how it is implemented. Note that it is irrelevant whether or not it is stored consecutively, as the API is defined in terms of indexes of bits set, which means that its outward behaviour will be ordered. And for example `toString` specifies: _" Such indices are listed in order from lowest to highest"_

Comment: Understood! Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The javadoc of [`nextClearBit`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#nextClearBit(int)) says:

> Returns the index of the first bit that is set to `false` that occurs on or after the specified starting index.

You have set 5, 6 and 9 to true. That means that starting from 5, the first index set to false is 7. And starting from 9, the first index set false is 10. Which according to your own output is also what is returned.

If you want to know how [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html) works and what it does, read its Javadoc and look at the source. It is included with the JDK.

Comment: I want to know how the values are mapped to each other. Here in the bitset, values are given as 5,9, 6 but it actually stored it as 5,6,9.

Comment: @vicky That is because the output of [`BitSet.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/BitSet.html#toString()) is specified in the javadoc to be ordered. And again, if you want to know how it is actually implemented: look at the source. Last time I looked it is encoded in one or more longs so 5 sets the sixth bit and 6 the seventh bit, 9 the tenth bit of the first long (index 0 is the first bit), etc. But this is could be different in different versions of Java (or different vendors).

Answer (score 1):

`BitSet` uses bits to store the information, like this:

```
         ╔═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╦═══╗
Bits:    ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 1 ║ 1 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║ 0 ║
      ...╚═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╩═══╝
Position: 10   9   8   7   6   5   4   3   2   1   0
```

Whenever you use `set(n)` - it **sets** the bit in the corresponding position. The underlying implementation is with a series of longs - but for understanding the API, it's enough to imagine it as a long array of bits - zeros and ones - like in the drawing. It extends itself if it needs to.

When it needs to look for the next clear bit after 5, goes to the bit number 5, and starts searching until it reaches a zero. Actually, the implementation is a lot faster, relying on bit-manipulation tricks, but again, to understand the API, that's how you can imagine it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates you might have thought that the result of `b.nextClearBit(i)` was somehow affected by the order in which the different bits where set to `true` or `false`.
This is false because `BitSet` does not remember the order in which indices were given values.

`next` means *"next in the order of the indices"* and not *"next in the order of having been values assigned"*.

`b.nextClearBit(i)` returns the smallest index `j` larger or equal than `i` for which `b.get(i) == false`.

Comment: Yes, I thought as you said but got it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

`BitSet` is a set. The order (of insertion) is irrelevant. The method just gives the index of the next higher clear bit.

The internal implementation has been explained in a previous question. For each method, you can check the source. (The code may contain obscure "bit bashing" (also available in `java.lang.Integer`/`java.lang.Long`, may be implemented as intrinsics).)

Comment: A `BitSet` is definitely ordered. It is encoded in one or more longs where the index corresponds to a bit in one of the longs.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The description of `java.util.List` is "An ordered collection (also known as a sequence)." It's not one of those. It's sorted with a natural order but not by anything that can be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are quoting `java.util.List`, a `BitSet` is not a real collection class (it is not a `java.util.Set` as you seem to think): _"This class implements a vector of bits that grows as needed. Each component of the bit set has a boolean value. The bits of a BitSet are indexed by nonnegative integers."_ Both the use of _vector_ and _indexed by nonnegative integers_ (and the rest of the documentation) make clear it is ordered (by index of the bits).